# Filtrar elemento en lista mediante variable en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy intentando evaluar un string obtenido en shell contra una lista en Python, pero al intentar hacer el `if .. in`, no me evalúa correctamente, no entra en la sentencia.

```
import subprocess

output_domain = subprocess.check_output("domainname -f", shell=True)
print(output_domain)

domain_name = ['abc.corp', 'earth.corp']

if output_domain in domain_name:
    print("Dominio " + output_domain + " encontrado!")
else:
    print("Dominio no encontrado")
```

salida por pantalla:

```
ph0b0x@earth:~$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ph0b0x/python/hello_world.py
earth.corp

Dominio no encontrado
```

La variable es correctamente almacenada y se muestra "earth.corp" pero la sentencia `if` no.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola ph0b0x, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Puedes mostrar que te imprime `print(repr(output_domain))`?

Comment: Hola FJSevilla gracias, me muestra lo siguiente ahora:

ph0b0x@earth:~$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ph0b0x/python/hello_world.py
'earth.corp\n'
Dominio no encontrado

Sigue sin entrar, necesito que entre en el if. o usar otra cosa para evaluarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E problema es que la salida del subproceso añade un salto de línea al final, por lo que debes comparar con:

```
domain_name = ['abc.corp\n', 'earth.corp\n']
```

o usar `str.rstrip()` para eliminarlo previamente:

```
import subprocess

output_domain = subprocess.check_output("domainname -f", shell=True).rstrip()

domain_name = ['abc.corp', 'earth.corp']

if output_domain in domain_name:
    print("Dominio {} encontrado!".format(output_domain))
else:
    print("Dominio no encontrado")
```

Te recomiendo abandonar Python 2 y pasarte a Python 3, la rama 2 está oficialmente descontinuado desde el 1 de Enero de 2020 no se publicarán más parches de seguridad ni recibirá mejoras (esto hace más tiempo que tampoco se hacía).